# AWS lambda response ERROR: string indices must be integers (Textract)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm new to this and have spent 3 weeks on this error. I'm trying to get the response from a lambda function of the extracted text in an image in an s3 bucket. I successfully upload the image into the bucket from me expo project using this code:

```
try {
                const response = await fetch(data.uri);
                const blob = await response.blob();
                const assetType = 'Mobile Device';
                await Storage.put(`${username}/${assetType}/${UUID}`, blob, {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                    progressCallback,
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error uploading file:", err);
            }
```

this will invoke the lambda function to extract the needed text

```
import json
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bad_chars = [';', ':', '!', "*", ']', "[" ,'"', "{" , "}" , "'",","]
    
    file_obj = event["Records"][0]
    bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
    filename = unquote_plus(str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"], encoding='utf-8'))
    
    textract = boto3.client('textract', region_name='ap-south-1')
    
    print(f"Bucket: {bucketname} ::: Key: {filename}")

    response = textract.detect_document_text(
        Document={
            'S3Object': {
                "Bucket": bucketname,
                "Name": filename,
            }
        }
    )
    
    result=[]
    processedResult=""
    for item in response["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "WORD":
            result.append(item["Text"])
            element = item["Text"] + " "
            processedResult += element
        
    print (processedResult)    
    res=[]
    imei=""
    
    #Extracting imei number and removing the bad characters
    str_IMEI= str(re.findall('(?i)imei*?[1]*?[:]\s*\d{15}',processedResult))
    imei= str(re.findall('[^\]]+',str_IMEI))
    
    imei = str(imei.split(' ')[-1])
    
    for i in bad_chars :
        imei = imei.replace(i, '')

    if len(imei)>0 :
        res.append(str(imei))
    else:
        res.append('')
    
    #Extracting imei2 number and removing the bad characters
    str_IMEI2= str(re.findall('(?i)imei*?[2]*?[:]\s*\d{15}',processedResult))
    imei2= str(re.findall('[^\]]+',str_IMEI2)) 
    
    imei2 = str(imei2.split(' ')[-1])
    
    for i in bad_chars :
        imei2 = imei2.replace(i, '')

   
    if len(imei2)>0 :
        res.append(str(imei2))
    else:
        res.append('')

    #Extracting model number and removing the bad characters
    
    str_Model = str(re.findall('(?i)model*?[:]\s*[\w|\d|_,-|A-Za-z]+\s*[\w|\d|_,-|A-Za-z]+',processedResult)) 
    result = str(str_Model.split(' ')[-1])
    
    for bad_char in bad_chars :
        result = result.replace(bad_char, '')

    if len(result) >0 :
        res.append(result)
    else:
        res.append('')
    
    print(res)
  
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        #'body': JSON.stringify(result)
        'body': res
    }
```

and then use RESTapi to get the response from the lambda

```
try{
                const targetImage = UUID + '.jpg';
                const response = await fetch(
                    'https://6mpfri01z0.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev',
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            Accept: "application/json",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"                            
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(targetImage)
                    }
                )
                const OCRBody = await response.json();
                console.log('OCRBody', OCRBody);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error extracting details:", err);
            }
```

but i keep getting this error

```
OCRBody Object {
  "errorMessage": "string indices must be integers",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "8042d6f7-44de-4a54-8209-fe93ca8570ec",
  "stackTrace": Array [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler
    file_obj = event[\"Records\"][0]
",
  ],
}
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: `file_obj = event["Records"][0]` It looks like you're expecting `event` to be a dictionary, but it's actually a string.

Comment: Try this solution (translated from Japanese) https://jpcodeqa-com.translate.goog/q/f2fc50accd91b2012d31260e576811ff?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: You appear to using syntax for a Lambda that responds to an S3 event.  When your lambda is run directly, it won't have that structure.  Print out the contents of the event in your lambda to see what format it has

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are trying to slice a string type with a some kind of key as if it were a dict type:

```
>>> str_name = 'Jhon Doe'
>>> str_name['name']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Now that you know that the data you are treating as a dict is received as a str, you have everything you need to figure it out on your own. The error for which you made the post is not a bug in boto3, it's just a python stuff

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, this issue could cause, that you do not receive the correct data in header.
In all of my Lambda function, is use something like this:

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

Event is most of the time a valid dict within Python, so you have two possibilities here:

**Option 1**

Before proceeding, to something like

```
if 'Records' in event:
  if 's3' in event['Records'][0]:
    if 'bucket' in ...
      if 'name' in ...
```

Only if all condition are true, you should proceed.

**Option 1**
do a simple

```
print(event)
```

and check your event, when your Lambda will be failing.

The issue here could cause that the Lambda is triggered before the S3 object is available.

What you can do is to add a S3 trigger which will be invoked automatically the Lambda, as soon as the S3 object was uploaded. See here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I receive a response in  cloudwatch with all the text i extracted with no errors when ever i comment out the try/catch api section in my project application. Could it be a problem with the way i call the response?